# TFS Customer Web Interface

Tags: tfs

Is there any TFS Customer Relationship Web Interface available (like CodePlex) which enable customers to follow project progress with Bug Tracking (WorkItems), Discussions, Documentations, Release Upload etc..

EDIT:

TFS Web Access has not enough features for that purpose ...

Comment: What Process Template are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to expose information about the progress of the project, the most obvious solution might be simply to extend the TFS project's SharePoint site (this is where Discussions and Documentation can easily be held) and make use of the existing Reporting Services to build required reports.